# Counting identical records in a SQL table with respect to a column

Tags: sql, sqlite, unique

## Problem Description

I am looking for a SQL query that can create table 2 using table 1. I've thought of way to do this but it's not very eloquent and would prefer something simpler if possible.

**TABLE 1:**

| ID | Col_1 | Col_2 | Col_3 | Col_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | A | Q | R | U |
| 02 | A | Q | R | P |
| 03 | A | Q | R | U |
| 04 | A | Q | R | P |
| 05 | A | Q | T | U |
| 06 | A | Q | T | P |
| 07 | A | Q | T | U |
| 08 | A | Q | T | P |
| 09 | A | Q | R | U |
| 10 | B | Q | R | P |
| 11 | B | Q | R | U |
| 12 | B | Q | R | P |
| 13 | B | Q | T | U |
| 14 | C | Q | T | P |
| 15 | C | Q | T | U |
| 16 | C | Q | T | U |
| 17 | C | Q | R | P |
| 18 | C | Q | R | U |
| 19 | C | Q | R | P |
| 20 | C | Q | R | U |

**TABLE 2:**

| ID | Col_1 | Col_2 | Col_3 | Col_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 9 | 9 | 5 | 3 |
| 02 | 9 | 9 | 5 | 2 |
| 03 | 9 | 9 | 5 | 3 |
| 04 | 9 | 9 | 5 | 2 |
| 05 | 9 | 9 | 4 | 2 |
| 06 | 9 | 9 | 4 | 2 |
| 07 | 9 | 9 | 4 | 2 |
| 08 | 9 | 9 | 4 | 2 |
| 09 | 9 | 9 | 5 | 3 |
| 10 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 2 |
| 11 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 12 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 2 |
| 13 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 14 | 7 | 7 | 3 | 1 |
| 15 | 7 | 7 | 3 | 2 |
| 16 | 7 | 7 | 3 | 2 |
| 17 | 7 | 7 | 4 | 2 |
| 18 | 7 | 7 | 4 | 2 |
| 19 | 7 | 7 | 4 | 2 |
| 20 | 7 | 7 | 4 | 2 |

The numbers in Table 2 are generated as follows:

In Table 2's Col_1, the number is the count of all IDs that have the same Col_1 value.
In Table 2's Col_2, the number is the count of all IDs that have the same Col_1 ***AND*** Col_2 value.
In Table 2's Col_3, the number is the count of all IDs that have the same Col_1 ***AND*** Col_2 ***AND*** Col_3 value.
In Table 2's Col_4, the number is the count of all IDs that have the same Col_1 ***AND*** Col_2 ***AND*** Col_3 ***AND*** Col_4 value.

**Example:**
In Table 1, ID01's Col_1 value is 'A'. 'A' matches with  02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, and 09 (8 other IDs) so the number is 9.
ID01's Col_2 value is 'Q'. 'A' in Col_1 ***AND*** 'Q' in Col_2 matches with  02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, and 09 (8 other IDs) so the number is 9.
ID01's Col_3 value is 'R'. 'A' in Col_1 ***AND*** 'Q' in Col_2  ***AND*** 'R' in Col_3 matches with  02, 03, 04, and 09 (4 other IDs) so the number is 5.
ID01's Col_4 value is 'U'. 'A' in Col_1 ***AND*** 'Q' in Col_2  ***AND*** 'R' in Col_3 ***AND*** 'U' in Col_4 matches with 03 and 09 (2 other IDs) so the number is 3.

Essentially, we are trying to find the total number of identical IDs in Table 1 - with respect to the Col of interest.

## What I've tried

I figured out a way to get the numbers in Table 2, with short SQL queries:

```
-- Somehow use in Table 2 
SELECT 
    col_1,
    col_2,
    col_3,
    col_4,
    COUNT() AS ct
FROM sample_table
GROUP BY 
    col_1,
    col_2,
    col_3,
    col_4
ORDER BY ct DESC;
```

this returns

| Col_1 | Col_2 | Col_3 | Col_4 | ct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Q | R | U | 3 |
| A | Q | R | P | 2 |
| A | Q | T | P | 2 |
| A | Q | T | U | 2 |
| B | Q | R | P | 2 |
| C | Q | R | P | 2 |
| C | Q | R | U | 2 |
| C | Q | T | U | 2 |
| B | Q | R | U | 1 |
| B | Q | T | U | 1 |
| C | Q | T | P | 1 |

which are the correct numbers (ct) for Col_4 of Table 2. I would just need to match the columns in this output and Table 1. I can also `GROUP BY`fewer Columns to get the correct numbers for Col_3, Col_2, and 1. e.g.

```
SELECT 
    col_1,
    col_2,
    col_3,
    COUNT() AS ct
FROM samptbl
GROUP BY 
    col_1,
    col_2,
    col_3
ORDER BY ct DESC;
```

| Col_1 | Col_2 | Col_3 | ct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Q | R | 5 |
| A | Q | T | 4 |
| C | Q | R | 4 |
| B | Q | R | 3 |
| C | Q | T | 3 |
| B | Q | T | 1 |

I'm doing this in SQLite right now but I can use any other language if needed (PostgreSQL, Python). I would really like this to be 100% in a SQL if possible. The data sets that I'm working with are large, so good efficiency is desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with window function `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT ID,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Col_1) Col_1,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Col_1, Col_2) Col_2,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Col_1, Col_2, Col_3) Col_3,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_4) Col_4
FROM table1
ORDER BY ID
```

Without any changes it works for Postgresql also.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6211918bf3db0361b76d457689c62372).

Comment: Thank you forpas, I tried this and it took me ~150 seconds to run. Better than I could have possibly hoped for! Would you have any insights as to the efficiency of this approach vs Turo's. ( I will try both and report back...)

Comment: If 150 seconds is better that you hoped then you must have a rather large table. Usually window functions perform better than simple aggregation. In your case you could test the performance with an index for each case: Col_1, (Col_1, Col_2), (Col_1, Col_2, Col_3) and (Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_4).

Answer (score 1):

You could use CREATE TABLE AS amd simple subselects:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE2 AS
SELECT a.ID, 
        (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM samptbl WHERE a.col_1 = col_1) as col_1, 
        (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM samptbl WHERE a.col_1 = col_1 and a.col_2 = col_2)  as col_2, 
        (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM samptbl WHERE a.col_1 = col_1 and a.col_2 = col_2 and a.col_3 = col_3)  as col_3,
        (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM samptbl WHERE a.col_1 = col_1 and a.col_2 = col_2 and a.col_3 = col_3 and a.col_4 = col_4)  as col_4
FROM samptbl a;
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/1290)

But the efficiency won't be good...

Comment: Thank you much, this was very useful! This was the direction my mind was headed. I have not compared the performance of this to forpas's solution.